# Altering a query to consolidate answers in a poll

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.description, a.id, a.answer, q.id, q.question
                    FROM x_trybe_poll_relation pr
                        LEFT JOIN x_polls p
                            ON pr.poll_id = p.id
                        LEFT JOIN x_polls_question_relation qr
                            ON p.id = qr.poll_id
                        LEFT JOIN x_polls_questions q
                            ON qr.question_id = q.id
                        LEFT JOIN x_polls_answers a
                            ON q.id = a.question_id
                    WHERE pr.trybe_id = '%s'
```

Which returns:

```
[polls] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 79de13af1978ab14f56b4305956b2d93cd42e0fb
                    [title] => Poll 1
                    [description] => Poll 1 Description
                    [answer] => Danny Welbeck
                    [question] => Who is the best player in the Arsenal squad?
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 79de13af1978ab14f56b4305956b2d93cd42e0fb
                    [title] => Poll 1
                    [description] => Poll 1 Description
                    [answer] => Alexis Sanchez
                    [question] => Who is the best player in the Arsenal squad?
                )

        )
```

How do I adjust the mysql query to get the following:

```
[polls] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 79de13af1978ab14f56b4305956b2d93cd42e0fb
            [title] => Poll 1
            [description] => Poll 1 Description
            [answers] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array (
                    [id] => abc
                    [answer] => Danny Welbeck
                ) 
                [1] => Array (
                    [id] => def
                    [answer] => Alexis Sanchez
                ) 
            )
            [question] => Who is the best player in the Arsenal squad?
        )


)
```

I want to get the poll question, and get the array of pre-generated answers with one query.

Is this possible, or should I just run two queries?

Thanks

Comment: a million times easier to run two queries.  Run a query to get the question information, then a second query to get all answers associated with that question.

Comment: yep, but is there a way to do it with one query?

Comment: Probably, but I can't think of how to get it to return exactly how you have it.  You already are getting all the data you need.  If you just want it in one line item per question, you could use group concat, and process that column with a string parser to break it up into its component parts.

Comment: Yeah its annoying, i've just come to a massive wall, just cant think of the solution! :( with the 2 query solution suggestion. I'd have to do a foreach and query every question. Which would not be good at all.

Comment: you could use group concat and build in your HTML or whatever into it.  THen you have a column in your data that gets returned that can be just inserted into the block where your answers would go.

Comment: so what i'd want to do is get the result as above, and then foreach through the answers array. :/ Just hope someone with a couple more braincells than me can offer that solution haha

Comment: i'm looking into group concat @MarshallTigerus thanks

Comment: making queries more complicated than they have to be isn't good for the DBA or the database.

Comment: but its a lot tidier, and probably saves my app loading time